# Problems with setting up Hadoop 2.6.0 multinode on ubuntu 14

Tags: hadoop

I am following this --- 
1) http://www.kishorer.in/2014/09/setting-up-single-node-hadoop-241_20.html
2) http://www.kishorer.in/2014/10/setting-up-hadoop-241-multi-node.html

Now , here are the problems --
1) namenode doesnot start on hadoopmaster .
2) when I type hadoopmaster:50070 in the URL , it shows that domain name not found .

The network configuration is : 
hadoopmaster 10.0.10.161
hadoopslave1 10.0.10.162

The hosts file on each machine is as 
127.0.0.1 localhost

10.0.10.161 hadoopmaster
10.0.10.162 hadoopslave1

So ,
1) Is there any problem with the hosts file ?
2) Any other problem ?  Maybe another tutorial ?
3) In the above tutorial for multinode , are the contents of the xml files ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Namenode doesnot start means it might be caused by many issues. PLease check below before proceeding .

1. Check the namenode logs.
2. Check the configuration files, they need to be consistent in cluster.
3. check /etc/hosts file if all the details are maintained.

Please update your namenode logs if the issue doesnot get resolved after performing these checks.

Comment: Can you share your
1) hosts file
2) master and slaves file
3) hdfs-site.xml
4) core-site.xml
5) mapred-site.xml
6) yarn-site.xml